# How to change icon by clicking on the div not only the icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Following code changes icon by clicking on the icon but how do I make it so that icon change by clicking on anywhere in the div or clicking on the link which is in the same div as the icon.

html:

```
<div class="btn">
    <i  onclick="changeIcon(this)" class="far fa-square-plus"></i>
    <a class="add" href="#">addon</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
changeIcon = (icon) => icon.classList.toggle("fas")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the event.target to get the parent node and then query the `i` element using `e.target.parentNode.querySelector('i')` this will get the target element, then use `.classList.toggle("fas")` to toggle on click.

Also I recommend using an eventListener `click` over inline HTML `onclick` attribute for your function callback.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

const changeIcon = (e) => e.target.parentNode.querySelector('i').classList.toggle("fas");

btn.addEventListener('click', changeIcon);
```

```css
.btn {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn">
  <i class="far fa-square-plus"></i>
  <a class="add" href="#">addon</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="btn" onclick="changeIcon(this)">    
    <i class="far fa-square-plus"></i>
    <a class="add" href="#">addon</a>
</div>
```

This will trigger your function whenever you click inside the div.